# Can't get private keys for my bitcoin wallet on own node

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I deployed bitcoin prune node on my own server and can't figure out how to get the private keys for my wallet. `getwalletinfo` doesn't return my wallet number, but `dumpprivkey` requires it:

```
curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "method": "getwalletinfo"}'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://login:pwd@127.0.0.1:8332/
{"result":{"walletname":"takoe2","walletversion":169900,"format":"bdb","balance":0.00000000,"unconfirmed_balance":0.00000000,"immature_balance":0.00000000,"txcount":0,"keypoololdest":1690405258,"keypoolsize":1000,"hdseedid":"37acbef925f63c49a0ddf1ba118c3782a480e9c2","keypoolsize_hd_internal":1000,"paytxfee":0.00000000,"private_keys_enabled":true,"avoid_reuse":false,"scanning":false,"descriptors":false},"error":null,"id":null}
```

The node is working, the blocks are syncing, I can generate the new addresses for accept the payments from my website, but I worry what will happened if the server goes down forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch your private keys **from your own Bitcoin node**, follow these two steps:

1. **Find all your Bitcoin addresses:**

Run the `listaddressgroupings` command. It looks like:

```bash
curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "listaddressgroupings", "params": [] }'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://login:pwd@127.0.0.1:8332/
```

This will return a list of all addresses in your wallet.

2. **Fetch private keys for each address:**

Use the `dumpprivkey` command with each address from the list you just obtained:

```bash
curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "dumpprivkey", "params": ["Your_Bitcoin_Address_Here"] }'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://login:pwd@127.0.0.1:8332/
```

Replace `"Your_Bitcoin_Address_Here"` with each actual address. You'll get their respective private keys.

Remember, these keys are critical - they give full control over the funds linked with their addresses. Keep them safe. If your server ever goes down, you can restore your funds using these keys. Back up your wallet regularly for extra safety.

#### Update base on first comment

To **send Bitcoin from multiple addresses in one go**, you can use the `sendmany` command. It allows you to send funds from all your wallet addresses to **one or more addresses in a single transaction**. Here's how:

```bash
curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "sendmany", "params": ["", {"recipient_address":amount,...} ] }'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://login:pwd@127.0.0.1:8332/
```

Just replace `"recipient_address"` with the address you want to send to, and `"amount"` with the number of Bitcoins to send.

**Remember**, this action **can link your addresses together on the blockchain**, which **might affect your privacy**. Also, make sure you include a sufficient transaction fee for prompt processing. Bitcoin Core usually handles this, but it's good to double-check.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just wondering how could I send these money from all the addresses, because I generate the new address for each payment on my website. I believe there will be hundreds of addresses. Can I somehow send the money from all of them in one transaction?

Comment: Looks like i understand. I should collect the money from all the addresses automatically when the transaction will be approved. Thank you